# Check if a keyword is in a string

Tags: java

I have a list of keywords and I want to be able to find if a string contains any of those keywords. Right now the solution I have takes O(n). Is there a quicker way of doing this search without looping through each keywords and doing a comparison/contains?

i.e.
Keywords = "cat", "hat", "mat", "bat", "fat", "sat", "rat", "pat", "foo bar", "foo-bar"
String = "There is a cat in the box." 
The result of this is true because "cat" matches one of the words in the 'keywords'

EDIT: 
I guess I wasn't as clear when I said O(n). I mean to say O(n) where n=number of keywords.

Comment: How can you possibly find out a string of length N has none of the words in less than O(N)?!?

Comment: One crude way would be to check if your input ends with "at" or "bar". If so, check if it starts with the corresponding first part of the keyword. It's rather ugly, I'm sure there are more suited algorithms/datastructures for this. But then again: Big-O notation is worst case scenario. The worst case scenario is **always** N at best. What you're looking for would be Big-Theta which defines an average, likely scenario.

Comment: is that n in O(n) the length of the string or the # of keywords?

Comment: @bcorso, The length of the string is definitely a factor.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel, Big-O is not just for worst case, though it is best suited for worst case. Also, the worst case is not always N. Even with the naïve approach, it won't take N of anything to find out the first keyword is in the first position.

Comment: I think there is a way to go below O(N). Something close to how Shazam hashes different songs in partial bits and checks smaller subsets against bigger sets.

Comment: I think @JeroenVannevel is right... In such circumstances you shouldnt go for O(n) you should go for theta (n) i.e, avg case efficiency. O(n) doesnt give a clearer picture

Comment: The naïve approach would still be written as O(N), despite the possibility of O(1) (which is what I was referring to when saying Big-O is expressed as worstcase). Slight amendement: It's the tilde notation that defines an average, not the big-theta.

Comment: @user459811, Boyer-Moore matches substrings not words, so "cat" is a match for "catepillar". If you want to match just words you can actually get a better running time, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), which involves preprocessing the string, but you're not going to be able to beat a worst case of O(KN), where K is the sum of the lengths of the keywords, and N is the length of the string.  Best case is of course sublinear, but you can't have a worst case sublinear runtime.

Note that the comparisons aren't free.  It's not like you can compare two strings in O(1) to see if they're equal, you have to iterate through the characters.  Hashing gets you to what you need to compare to in constant time, but doesn't help more than that since two different strings can have the same hash.  That's not to say that hashing isn't good, it is, but it does not alter the worst case runtime complexity.

In the end, you need to compare the characters, and Boyer-Moore provides a very good way to do that.  Of course if you're using some sort of hash based build, you may be able to rule out certain keywords in amortized constant time, but that doesn't change the fact that in the worst case (and many other cases), you're going to need to compare characters.

Also note that depending on what we assume about the data, and how we construct our indexing structure(s), it's possible to achieve a very good actual runtime.  Just because the worst case complexity isn't sublinear doesn't mean that the actual runtime won't be really fast.  There is no singleton simple or correct solution, the problem can be approached in myriad ways.  There's never a quick and dirty answer to solve all of your problems when it comes to information retrieval.

Comment: The Boyer-Moore string searching algorithm is used in java Pattern implementation.

Comment: @bcorso Hashing allows you to quickly see what you need to compare to, but you still need to compare the strings.  Worst case, that's going to be O(KN).  That's not to say that hashing isn't good, it's to say that hashing doesn't change the worst case complexity.

Comment: @SteveP. I'm not sure I get it.  Hashing a word takes O(N), where N is the length of the word but once you have a hash comparing them is O(1)

Comment: I think the most important part is the last addendum: O(N) is the theoretical maximin to be obtained and the one that's used in complexity calculations, but the realistic results will be (a lot) better, depending on other factors like how the data looks.

Comment: @bcorso Say you have a hash table and we have a keyword that maps to a slot with only one word in it.  How do we compare those two strings?  We have to compare the characters that's `min(O(k), O(n))`, right?  Now, let's assume that the sentence is only one word, with length N.  Now we have K comparisons, so our overall complexity is `O(KN)`.

Comment: @SteveP. I'm thinking of a HashSet not a HashMap, where each element in the set is a word in the sentence.

Comment: @bcorso Same principle still applies, though.  No matter what, at some point you're going to have to compare characters.  Hashing in whatever way you cut it doesn't remove character comparison.  Obviously if you're using a hash-structure and your keyword doesn't map to anything, then yes that will be constant time, but we're talking worse case here.

Comment: Since a hashcode is represented as an integer: aren't integers compared in O(1) at bitwise level?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Two different strings can have the same hash code, which is the issue.  That's why you have to compare characters.  Think about it, there are infinitely many possible strings, but a finite number of `Integers`, at least with respect to java.  All that a hashcode guarantees is that two equal objects have the same hashcode, **not** two objects with the same hashcode are equal.

Comment: @SteveP.: ah ofcourse, totally overlooked that. Worst case scenario will be O(KN) indeed, best case and average case will probably be a lot better (I don't expect many hash collisions).

Comment: @SteveP. I thought since Strings were immutable same strings reference the same memory. Wont it just compare the reference?

Comment: Nevermind, that's only String literals, not Strings created at runtime. Anyway, thanks

Comment: @bcorso That's assuming that the original string is in the string pool and the keyword has been interned.  If this is true, you are correct, but that's an assumption not intrinsic to the problem...no problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
k = # of chars in sentence
n = # of keywords
m = # of words in sentence
```

You can get `O(k + n)` time complexity by hashing the words in `sentence`.

Separating the sentence into words takes `O(k)`. Creating the HashSet also takes `O(k)`. Checking the hash `n` times takes `n*O(1) = O(n)`, so the overall time complexity is `O(k + n)`.

---

**Edit1:** Hashing all `n` keywords is technically `n*O(k/m)`, where `k/m` is avg. word length. However, `k/m` does not scale with the size of the input, so it still gives `O(n)`.

---

**Edit2:** FYI, Boyer-Moore will match any substring, not just keywords; E.g. "cat" will match "catepillar". Also, because it is more general it has a worse running time than a simple word match, `O(KN)` as @SteveP. has in his answer.

So if you only need word matching, as opposed to substring matching,  stick with hashing as above.

Answer (score 1):

Could try using contains().

Get the String; String passed = "there is a cat in the box";

use for loop to go through your key words. if keywords is an array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++){
    if(passed.toLowerCase().contains(keywords[i]){
        //set true;
    }else{
        //set false;
    }
}
```

Either going through a loop or checking each word individually, i dont think you'll get much better than O(n)

Answer (score 0):

not sure it will find inO(n).

but the solution to find the element could be like this

```
  List<String>  keywords = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList("cat", "hat", "mat", "bat", "fat", "sat", "rat", "pat", "foo bar", "foo-bar"));
  String search= "There is a cat in the box." ;   
  List<String>  searchWords = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(search.split(" ")));     
  System.out.println(!Collections.disjoint(keywords,searchWords));
```

Comment: What will happen if he put comma inside the sentence? Like "There is a cat, it is in the box." Or "There is a cat. It's in a box"

Comment: @Eddie, How to tokenize a sentence is incidental. If the OP has a problem with that, he can bring it up as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not going to get any better than O(n), since there's a linear component to this piece - you have to trawl the string in some shape, form, or fashion.

Consider using a `Set`:

- Constant-time to add all of the elements (could be amoritized to N for N elements)
- Constant-time look up for existence

```
public boolean inPhrase(String phrase, String searchWord) {
    Set<String> phraseSet = new HashSet<>();
    // remove the punctuation and split the words on white space.
    for(String s:  phrase.replaceAll("[.,?!;"'], "").split(" ")) {
        phraseSet.add(s);
    }
    return phraseSet.contains(searchWord);
}
```